# Phaser - Can't allow a multiple key event

Tags: javascript, events, phaser-framework

I'm programming a simple platformer game, and I'm programming and setting the movement of the player. Here's my update function:

```
update: function () {

    game.physics.arcade.collide(this.player, this.platform);
    game.camera.follow(this.player);

        if(this.cursor.right.isDown){
            this.player.body.velocity.x= 200;
            this.player.animations.play('correr', 5, true);
            this.player.scale.x=1;
        }

        else if(this.cursor.left.isDown){
            this.player.body.velocity.x= -200;
            this.player.animations.play('correr', 5, true);
            this.player.scale.x=-1;
        }

        else if(this.jump.isDown && this.player.body.wasTouching.down) {
            this.player.body.velocity.y= -400
        }   

        else if((this.cursor.right.isDown || this.cursor.left.isDown) && this.jump.isDown){
            this.player.body.velocity.x= 200;
            this.player.body.velocity.y=-200;
        }

        else{
            this.player.body.velocity.x = 0;
            this.player.animations.stop();
            this.player.frame = 4;
        }
    }
```

Everything works fine, but in my last else if is suppose that the player should jump and walk, but it doesn't work! My intention is the player could jump while walking pressing the jump key + left or right key, for now I just can jump first and then walk.

I don't know why this last else isn't being executed, because I tried to move it in the first if clause and it worked perfectly, but I can't determine the error.

Thanks for helping.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is your first couple if/else statements.

These two bits will capture all right and left arrow keys.

```
if (this.cursor.right.isDown) {
    // Code is checked first, and will trigger if the right arrow key is down. Nothing else will trigger.
} else if (this.cursor.left.isDown){
    // Code is checked second, and will trigger if the left arrow key is down. Nothing else will trigger.
}
```

That means that this will never trigger.

```
} else if ((this.cursor.right.isDown || this.cursor.left.isDown) && this.jump.isDown) {
    // Code will never trigger, since right and left are covered by your first two if/else statements.
}
```

One option would be to do multiple if/else statements.

```
// here, reset the player velocity
this.player.body.velocity.x = 0;

if (this.cursor.right.isDown) {
    // code
} else if (this.cursor.left.isDown) {
    // code
} else {
    this.player.animations.stop();
    this.player.frame = 4;
{

if (this.jump.isDown && this.player.body.touching.down) {
    // code
} else if (...) {
    // code as needed
}
```

The official Phaser tutorial [covers this in part 6](https://phaser.io/tutorials/making-your-first-phaser-game/part6).

Comment: Thanks, I'll try that way. However I fixed it moving the 

else if((this.cursor.right.isDown || this.cursor.left.isDown) && this.jump.isDown)

the first condition to evaluate, and solved everything.

Answer (score 0):

```
 this.player.body.velocity.x = 0;
```

should be starting state of the player, and one of the first lines of your update function, as you can say that it is his "idle" state.

Also i would recommend  jump timer

```
var jumpTimer = 0; 
...................
if(jump && (player.body.onFloor()||
 player.body.touching.down)&& this.time.now > jumpTimer){

        player.body.velocity.y = -400;
        jumpTimer = this.time.now + 750;
        player.animations.play('jump');
    }
```

More examples of phaser mechanics and be found here https://gamemechanicexplorer.com/#platformer-4